# Reading and Writing text file?

Tags: java, file-io

I'm suppose to write a program in which we ask the user for 2 files the first file is for reading and the second for writing
the first one we are suppose to read the file and then copy the info switch it all to uppercase and save it to the second file
I cant get it to write on the second part any help?

```
public class FileConverter 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the filename for the first file");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);

    while(inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        String fileinfo = inputFile.nextLine();
        String uppercaseinfo1 = fileinfo.toUpperCase();
    }

    System.out.print("Enter the filename "
                + "for the second file");
    filename = keyboard.nextLine();
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(file);

    while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            outputFile.println();
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `close()` the `PrintWriter`

```
...
while(inputFile.hasNext())
{
     outputFile.println();
}

ouputFile.close();
```

Also, You don't need two loops. Just do the transferring all in one loop. You need to make sure you have two different File objects. One for the input and one for the output. With different file names.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the filename for the first file");
String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
File file = new File(filename);                  // file 1
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);          // infile

System.out.print("Enter the filename "
        + "for the second file");
filename = keyboard.nextLine();
File file1 = new File(filename);                 // file 2
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(file1); // outfile

while(inputFile.hasNext())
{
    String fileinfo = inputFile.nextLine();
    String uppercaseinfo1 = fileinfo.toUpperCase();
    outputFile.println(uppercaeinfo1);
}

outputFile.close();
```

Comment: typo: uppercaeinfo1 :)

Comment: And this won't work if input and output files are one and the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need a FileWriter in there, and close it:

```
FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(filePath);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);

out.println("stuff");

out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only `close()` method is absent. Solution has some mistakes.

```
// corrected statements are marked with "!"
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the filename for the first file");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    String uppercaseinfo1 = "";                             // !
    while(inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        String fileinfo = inputFile.nextLine();
        uppercaseinfo1 += fileinfo.toUpperCase() + "\n";       // !
    }
    inputFile.close();          // !

    System.out.print("Enter the filename "
            + "for the second file");
    filename = keyboard.nextLine();
    file = new File(filename);                  // !
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(file);
    outputFile.println(uppercaseinfo1);         // !
    outputFile.close();                         // !
}
```

And, as rightly noted above, you must close input/output streams at the end, if you want changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use an instance of BufferedWriter to write into the file instead of PrintWriter.

e.g.

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename)); // create the write buffer

// to-do: EITHER surround with try-catch in order catch the IO Exception OR add throws declaration

bw.write("some text"); // content for the new line
bw.newLine();  // a line break

bw.flush(); // flush the buffer and write into the file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {


Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the filename for the first file");
String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

File file = new File(filename);
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);
System.out.print("Enter the filename "
            + "for the second file");
String filename2 = keyboard.nextLine();
File file2 = new File(filename2);
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(file2);

while(inputFile.hasNext())
{
    String fileinfo = inputFile.nextLine();
    String uppercaseinfo1 = fileinfo.toUpperCase();
    outputFile.println(uppercaseinfo1);
}
 outputFile.close()
}
}
```

I do it smth like this